# How to control which objects are imported from a module

Tags: python, import, package

I have a module and I would like to control which objects are imported from it. The structure is something like this:

```
/src
    /example_pkg
        __init__.py
        foo.py
    __init__.py
```

`__init__.py` is empty in both cases

`foo.py` looks like this:

```
import numpy as np

def foo_func():
    x = np.sin(1)
    print('sine of 1 is ' + str(x))
```

when I import foo as follows:

```
import foo
dir(foo)
```

I get this output:

```
['__builtins__',
 '__cached__',
 '__doc__',
 '__file__',
 '__loader__',
 '__name__',
 '__package__',
 '__spec__',
 'foo_func',
 'np']
```

For neatness I'd rather not import np with this so that when I type `foo.` and hit tab the autocomplete (in spyder for e.g.) just shows the objects from within my module. I'd rather the import command just automatically imported all of the objects created within `foo.py`. Is it possible to do this? I'd rather avoid `from foo import *` and defining all objects in `__init__.py`

I appreciate that this is a basic question but I have looked around and can't see an obvious answer.

Comment: Try `from foo import foo_func` to just import that one symbol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This really depends on your autocompleter, but it should honor the convention that `_`-prefixed names aren't for use outside the module itself. (`from foo import *` itself will ignore such names.)

Use

```
import numpy as _np
```